# Creating default values t.d <style> </style> at flutter

Tags: flutter

i want to create some default values like text size, background color etc, can i use the same logic as it is in android, is anyone that can help me. thanks

```
`<style name="Style">
  <item name="android:textSize">10pt</item>
</style>`
```

Comment: Unclear. What exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding text style we have **TextTheme** and the **TextStyle** classes that can help you with that.

You can set up a const **TextStyle** value in your **main.dart** file like this:

```
const style = const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 10.0,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
);
```

You can use this in any file that imports the main file:

```
import 'package:<you package name>/main.dart';
```

If you want a global style specific to your need depending on the text type, you can use a **TextTheme**. You have to pass this values to you **MaterialApp** widget like this:

```
    new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          //the styles you want
        )
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    )
```

Then in you code, especially in your build methods where you have a **BuildContext** reference, you can call:

```
Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1;
```

Comment: Yes I did saw this and it's different from android, but let's say we want to build an multilingual app, where can I store the values, does flutter have like resources file <style> <item>... Thanks

Comment: Not yet. But if you want internalisation for strings you can use my Intellij plugin for this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n

Comment: Thank you very much, flutter is brilliant.

Comment: You're right, don't forget to thumb up the answer if it helped.

Comment: Half the answer, theme text style fonts are at the documentation but I wasn't sure for the whole part (including internationalisation and possibility to use the same logic as android...)
Thanks, very much appreciate it.